# how to send kernel command line parameter in raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, spectre

I need to send kernel command line parameter in raspbian os to turn off spectre/meltdown patches. as i know we can do this in other linux distros through "/etc/default/grub" file by changing "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=". but in raspbian os this file did not exist and even "grub-update" command and also "grub-mkconfig" did not installed.

could anyone tell me how i can pass kernel command line parameter in raspbian os?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` with any editor in privilege mode.

```sh
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

This would allow you to send any kernel command.
[source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/cmdline-txt.md)

> However, I think the mitigation isn't [built in Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244166).

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation on how to add kernel command line arguments](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/cmdline-txt.md) you have to edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` with the kernel options you want to pass.

Comment: Thanks, just another question. after adding kernel command line parameter in /boot/cmdline.txt do I need to do anything more like updating grub or etc? or I just need a reboot RPI.